# Odoo v10: ¿Como copiar el contenido de un campo One2many en otro campo One2many?

Tags: python, odoo

Quisiera saber como copiar un campo One2many, es decir digamos que tengo 2 campos One2many que apuntan a modelos distintos, y en ambos modelos estan los mismos campos, y quiero crear un metodo donde todo el contenido del primer campo One2many me lo copie en el segundo campo One2many, no se si me explique... espero sus respuestas, Saludos y gracias de antemano si puedes ayudarme.

Intente con este codigo de prueba para ver si funcionaba pero me da error:

```
def foo(self):
    detalles = self.env['detalle'].browse(self._context.get('active_ids', []))
    obj = self.env['detalle2contract']
    for r in self:
        for d in detalles:
            tipo = d.tipo
            descripcion = d.descripcion
            cantidad = d.cantidad
            unidad = d.unidad
            detalle2contract_id = d.detalle_id

    lines = obj.create({
        'tipo': tipo,
        'descripcion': descripcion,
        'cantidad' cantidad,
        'unidad': unidad,
        'detalle2contract_id': detalle2contract_id
        })

    return lines
```

Comment: Has intentado hacer algo? porque no nos muestras tu código para poder ayudarte?

Comment: Ya añadi el codigo que utilice... espero puedas ayudarme, aprecio tu ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

Tu pregunta tiene dos respuestas posibles según los escenarios que se deseen:

1.- Si deseas que cuando cambies algo en el primer campo One2Many se reflejen en el otro campo One2Many y en los modelos distintos. Te sugiero que utilices _inherits esto solo crea punteros (por decirlo asi), a los modelos originales, por lo que cualquier campo que sea cambiado en cualquier lugar su resultado se vera reflejado en todos las demás dependencias.

2.- Si solo deseas llenar los campos cuando se cree el record, debes modificar el método **create**, OJO si editas el record luego esos cambios no se veran reflejados en los otros modelos.